# How would I obtain a total sum of only selected rows for a specific column?

Tags: c#, linq

I was able to get a sum of the entire column but having trouble getting only selected items in my datagrids sum. Below is what I have so far:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    decimal sum = csv_datagridview.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                                  .Sum(row => Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[7].Value));
    MessageBox.Show("Total is: " + sum.ToString());
}
```

[image]

Comment: try `csv_datagridview.SelectedRows`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not `SelectedRows` instead for just `Rows`? the SelectedRows property of the DataGridView will gives you the selected rows, you can iterate through those rows and get the sum, see the code below:

```
 decimal sum =  csv_datagridview.SelectedRows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                 .Sum(row => Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[7].Value));
```

Comment: [***`yes`***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows(v=vs.110).aspx)